# Tensorflow keras: creating layer from config 'Keyword argument not understood:', 'axis'

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, keras-layer

**Code:**

```py
config = MCM_feature_extractor.get_layer(index=132).get_config()
x = tf.keras.layers.Layer()
x = x.from_config(config)
```

**config:**

```
{'axis': ListWrapper([3]),
 'beta_constraint': None,
 'beta_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}},
 'beta_regularizer': None,
 'center': True,
 'dtype': 'float32',
 'epsilon': 1.001e-05,
 'gamma_constraint': None,
 'gamma_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}},
 'gamma_regularizer': None,
 'momentum': 0.99,
 'moving_mean_initializer': {'class_name': 'Zeros', 'config': {}},
 'moving_variance_initializer': {'class_name': 'Ones', 'config': {}},
 'name': 'conv4_block5_preact_bn',
 'scale': True,
 'trainable': True}
```

**Am i doing it properly? i want to copy a few layers from the MCM model and use them to create another model using the functional API, then copy the weights.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution:**

```py
layer = MCM_feature_extractor.get_layer(index=132)
config = layer.get_config()
weights = layer.get_weights()

config['name'] = layer.name+'_2'
second_layer = type(layer).from_config(config)
second_layer.build(layer.input_shape)
second_layer.set_weights(weights)
second_layer = second_layer(title_input)
```